# How to place border lines on side of table with rotated text

Tags: tables, border

I'm trying to add the right side of this table's border/bounding box lines, it seems to delete it though it doesn't happen with other tables where I did not rotate the text to fit. I'd like to have two lines after "Industry Associations". My understanding is that the ||

```
\begin{tabular}{||p{10cm}cccccccccc||}
```

should apply the border lines.

[image: the table in question]

Code:

```
\begin{landscape}
\renewcommand*\rot[2]{\multicolumn{1}{R{#1}{#2}}}% no optional argument here, please!

\begin{tabular}{||p{10cm}cccccccccc||}
\hline\hline
NEEDS \& EXPECTATIONS OF INTERESTED PARTIES &   \rot{90}{1em}{Employees \& Contractors} &   \rot{90}{1em}{Customers, Clients \& Suppliers} &    \rot{90}{1em}{Regulators} &     \rot{90}{1em}{Registrar} &  \rot{90}{1em}{Generators} &     \rot{90}{1em}{General Public, Media \& NGOs} &  \rot{90}{1em}{Neighboring Businesses} &     \rot{90}{1em}{Insurers} &   \rot{90}{1em}{Emergency Response Services} &    \rot{90}{1em}{Industry Associations} &  \\ [0.5ex]
\hline\hline                                            
1. Expect to work in a safe and healthy environment &   X &      &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &      \\
\hline\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{landscape}
```

(More text is within but I cannot show it for confidentiality reasons, the table format remains.)

I am also using the packages:

```
\usepackage{rotating,graphicx} % allows for landscape tables
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{pdflscape} % Used to allow landscape pages
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{R}[2]{%
    >{\adjustbox{angle=#1,lap=\width-(#2)}\bgroup}%
    l%
    <{\egroup}%
}
\newcommand*\rot{\multicolumn{1}{R{45}{1em}}}% no optional argument here, please!
```

Comment: It is because your `\rot` definition involves a multicolumn, so the right border line needs to be in that multicolumn column specification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @TeddyvanJerry pointed out in the comment, the problem is that the specification for the double line, `||`, has to be repeated in a `\multicolumn` command in the last column, and there is one hidden in the definition of `\rot`. I will show two solutions: one with an extra argument for `\rot` to hand over this extra specification, and one where the frame is done with `\fbox`.

**Solution with third argument for `\rot`:** The command is used as `\rot{90}{1em}{}` and `\rot{90}{1em}{||}`, respectively.
[image]

```
\begin{landscape}
\renewcommand*\rot[3]{\multicolumn{1}{R{#1}{#2}#3}}%
%
\begin{tabular}{||p{10cm}cccccccccc||}
\hline\hline
NEEDS \& EXPECTATIONS OF INTERESTED PARTIES &
   \rot{90}{1em}{}{Employees \& Contractors} &
   \rot{90}{1em}{}{Customers, Clients \& Suppliers} &
   \rot{90}{1em}{}{Regulators} &
   \rot{90}{1em}{}{Registrar} &
   \rot{90}{1em}{}{Generators} &
   \rot{90}{1em}{}{General Public, Media \& NGOs} &
   \rot{90}{1em}{}{Neighboring Businesses} &
   \rot{90}{1em}{}{Insurers} &
   \rot{90}{1em}{}{Emergency Response Services} &
   \rot{90}{1em}{||}{Industry Associations}   \\ [0.5ex]
\hline\hline                                            
1. Expect to work in a safe and healthy environment &   X &      &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &      \\
\hline\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{landscape}
```

**Solution with `\fbox`:** Remove the specification `|` entirely, as well as the outer `\hline`s.
[image]

```
\begin{landscape}
\renewcommand*\rot[2]{\multicolumn{1}{R{#1}{#2}}}%
%
\fboxsep2pt%
\fbox{\fbox{%
\begin{tabular}{p{10cm}cccccccccc}
NEEDS \& EXPECTATIONS OF INTERESTED PARTIES &
   \rot{90}{1em}{Employees \& Contractors} &
   \rot{90}{1em}{Customers, Clients \& Suppliers} &
   \rot{90}{1em}{Regulators} &
   \rot{90}{1em}{Registrar} &
   \rot{90}{1em}{Generators} &
   \rot{90}{1em}{General Public, Media \& NGOs} &
   \rot{90}{1em}{Neighboring Businesses} &
   \rot{90}{1em}{Insurers} &
   \rot{90}{1em}{Emergency Response Services} &
   \rot{90}{1em}{Industry Associations}   \\ [0.5ex]
\hline\hline                                            
1. Expect to work in a safe and healthy environment &   X &      &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &      
\end{tabular}%
}}
```

Comment: The fbox solution worked perfectly! Thank you very much for the quick response.